# Java POI 3.16 XSSF pivot table - how to set label name to the first column

Tags: java, label, apache-poi, pivot-table

Why is the name of the first column in the pivot table not set automatically but the names of the following columns are set.

I generate the pivot table like this:

```
int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + firstDataRow;
int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
int firstCol = sheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
int lastCol = sheet.getRow(firstRow).getLastCellNum();

CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(firstRow, firstCol);
CellReference botRight = new CellReference(lastRow, lastCol - 1);

AreaReference areaRef = new AreaReference(topLeft, botRight);

XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(areaRef,
        new CellReference(firstRow, firstCol), sheet);

pivotTable.addRowLabel(lastCol - 1); // Month
pivotTable.addRowLabel(6); // User
pivotTable.addRowLabel(lastCol - 2); // State
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 0,
        resBundle.getString("WG_NM")); // count

CTPivotFields pFields = 
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();
pFields.getPivotFieldArray(lastCol - 1).setOutline(false);
pFields.getPivotFieldArray(6).setOutline(false);
pFields.getPivotFieldArray(lastCol - 2).setOutline(false);
```

Result is: [image]

The name of the first column should be month.

Is there a way to set it manually?